# How to pass parameter to getJSON in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, morris.js

I am using Morris jquery plugin to plot line chart. I am using PHP to get JSON encoded data. However, the URL is static. I am trying to make it generic where I could pass the username :

THe URL looks something like :

check_stats.php?command=visit&term=kirancshet". I would like to pass the username(term=kirancshet) attribute. Any idea how can I do this ?

```
$.getJSON('check_stats.php?command=visit&term=kirancshet', function(data) 
{       
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'morris-visit-stats-overall',
        data: data,
        xkey: 'label1',
        ykeys: ['visit'],
        labels: ['Date'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true

    });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic url in your request use `$.param`. It build query string from js object. Just set the desired value on 'term' property.

```
var obj = {
    command    : 'visit',
    term : 'kirancshet' //<- pass to obj any value to property 'term'
};

$.param(obj)// return 'command=visit&term=kirancshet'
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hh1o3mf9/1/) on jsfiddle.